# jquery data table child rows not working inside the bootstrap tabs

Tags: datatables

I am using two jquery data tables inside the bootstrap tabs.Now the child row extension(to show hidden td's in responsive) is not working on the second table in the second tab. and its working for the first data table. my code looks like this.
How to fix this issue.please guide me to fix this.
    enter code here

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://datatables.net/download/build/dataTables.responsive.nightly.js?_=8ee4d33682e599380ce4dd5cdd6f1f86"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );

    $('#example2').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );
    
  
     $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
 $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
});
        $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
} );
</script>
```

```html
<div class="container"><h1>Bootstrap  tab panel example</h1></div>
<div id="exTab1" class="container"> 
<ul  class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active">
        <a  href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Using nav-pills</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">Applying clearfix</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#4a" data-toggle="tab">Background color</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

      <div class="tab-content clearfix">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
           <div>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="2a">
          <div>

<table id="example2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="3a">
          <h3>We applied clearfix to the tab-content to rid of the gap between the tab and the content</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="4a">
          <h3>We use css to change the background color of the content to be equal to the tab</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```